# Python selenium - how to locate login elements on dynamic website that's only visible through inspect element

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to use Selenium in python to web scrape some data that is behind a login page. By viewing source, the page source code is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>sometitle</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="id1"></div>
    <div id="wrapper">Loading...</div>
    <div id="id2">
        ... some code ...
    </div>
        ... some code ...

    <script data-main="main" src="libs/requirejs.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried to use the following code to log into system and go to the next page, but it cannot find username/password elements in the above source code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
username = 'username'
password = 'password'

browser.get("https://sometitle.com")
browser.find_element_by_name("callback_0").send_keys(username)
browser.find_element_by_name("callback_1").send_keys(password)
browser.find_element_by_name("callback_2").click()
```

I then examined elements by inspect elements and found the elements on that page:

```
<div id="wrapper"><div id="login-base" class="base-wrapper">
    <div id="header" class="clearfix">
        ...
    </div>

    <div id="content" class="content"><div class="container-shadow" id="login-container" style="background-image: url(../images/box-bg.png);">
<br>
<h1>Header</h1>
    <form action="" method="post" class="form small">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="group-field-block">
                <label class="short">Username:</label><input type="username" name="callback_0" value="" data-validator="required" required="" data-validator-event="keyup">     
            </div>

            <div class="group-field-block">
                <label class="short">Password:</label><input type="password" name="callback_1" value="" data-validator="required" required="" data-validator-event="keyup">     
            </div>

            <div class="group-field-block float-left">
                <input name="callback_2" type="submit" class="button" index="0" value="Login">     
            </div>

            <ul class="link-box float-left"></ul>

        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

My question is - how can I locate the username/password/submit elements on the page that is only visible from inspect elements but not page source? Did some research, seems the website was built as dynamic website and it's redirecting to other page via jquery or javascript or something. I don't quite understand what's going on. Really appreciate some help or some insights!

Comment: There's no difference and generally your code is correct, except you should wait for the page to load before doing any "find_element" + make sure that login form is not inside an iframe

Comment: Are you asking that how do you use Selenium to locate the elements? Or how you can locate the elements with web browser's tool?

Comment: Hi @Kiril S. Thanks so much for reply! When I run the above selenium scripts, it has a "cannot locate the 'callback_0' (username) " error message. I tried reloading and waiting many times, but the page source is just as it is. This part <div id="wrapper">Loading...</div> wouldn't change. It's inner-html code is supposed to contain a form that uses POST methods that I'm looking for. But, it's not there. The form insider the <wrapper> can only be found when I do an inspect elements...

Comment: Hi @Buaban thanks so much for reply! I think I'm confused on why the elements I was looking for did not show up on the website source code. Since I'm using Selenium, if it can be done in selenium code, that'll be great. If not, what would be the good tool to use to locate the elements to send_key to automatically log onto the website. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you want to see updated source code, you can get it from browser.find_element_by_name('body').get_attribute('outerHTML').

Comment: @Buaban thanks. I tried, it printed the entire source code, but <div id="wrapper">Loading...</div> is still just it is. Btw, Don't know if it helps or not - when I was loading this page, it starts by displaying a blank page only with a "Loading..." message. After a few seconds, it brings up the colorful login page.

Comment: Did you have enough wait time? Try `browser.get("https://sometitle.com")` then `time.sleep(15)` then `browser.find_element_by_name('body').get_attribute('outerHTML')`. If it is still show the Loading, it might be because your login form are inside an iframe.

Comment: Thank you @Buaban Will give it a try!

Comment: Page source indeed never changes, and is therefore mostly useless. Most of the time you will  indeed have to inspect elements, it's normal. Learn selenium wait techniques (here: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp). For example the way suggested above with `time.sleep(15)` is ok to just check if indeed synchronization is a cause of your problems, but it should never be used in actual tests, instead use something like this: `driver.wait(function () {
    return driver.isElementPresent(webdriver.By.name("callback_0"));
}, 15);` this is much more reliable and less wasteful

Comment: @Buaban @Kiril S. You are right! Even though I still cannot locate the login elements on the login page, I did get code up and running. Used the wait techniques as you both suggested to let user manually type-in their login info. by `wait = WebDriverWait(driver,80)   wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_name("element1"))` I would still hope to be able to automatically log onto the page somehow, but I'm pretty happy that I can get this far! Again, thank you for your help!!